# Pointer made from an integer in C on an embedded platform

Tags: c, pointers, embedded

I came across the follow line of code:

```
    #define ADCA (*(volatile ADC_t*)0x200)
```

It is for embedded C code for an AVR microcontroller. `ADC_t` is a union.

I know that `(volatile ADC_t*)0x200` its a pointer to an absolute memory address but I am still not quite sure what the first `*` means.

Answer (score 12):

That first `*` dereferences the pointer. In other words `ADCA` is the contents of the memory at `0x200`.

Comment: Hey Thanks, just one more question: if I write something like ADCA = 0x01; the 0x01 value will be written in the memory address 0x200